# Android canvas rotate calculation

Tags: android, geometry

I'm creating a live wallpaper that I want a Picture to cover the entire canvas so I draw it like this when in landscape mode

```
Rectangle  r = new Rect(0, canvas.getHeight()- (canvas.getHeight()-statusBarHeight), canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());

c.drawPicture(pictureBackground, r);
```

Notice I have to take into consideration the status bar. Okay, that works fine. Now what I want to do is rotate the canvas 90 degrees for portrait mode (btw I can't just rotate the picture outside of code, have to do it this way) so I do this:

```
canvas.rotate(90,canvas.getWidth()/2,canvas.getHeight()/2);
```

Now what rectangle should I use to cover the canvas in its entirety when I go to draw the picture again (remember I have to account for the status bar)????

```
Rectangle  r = new Rect(?,?,?,?)
```

I can't figure it out, I've tried so many possible combinations

Comment: When you rotate screen height and width interchange so i think you do not need to change anything. And in both case status bar height will be same